# Divider line not showing in recycler view items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my app i am using a recycler view that contains a number of items, i want to show a doted separator(divider) line between the items but its not working. I have tried creating a drawable shape but afer adding drawable to **DividerItemDecoration** no space or line showing between the recycler view items. 
I have tried creating custom DividerItemDecoration class too but nothing works for me.
**NOTE:** Currently in my drawable shape is set to rectangle i have tried line too.
How it can be achieved. Any help will be appreciated.
Here is my code.

**Drawable:(customdrawableshape.xml)**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:height="2dp"
        android:color="#000000"
        android:dashGap="10dp"
        android:dashWidth="5dp" />

</shape>
```

**Custom row for recycler view items**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**And the part of code where i am setting item decoration to recyclerview**

```
DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration;
recyclerview.setLayoutManager(linearlayoutmanager);
dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerview.getContext(),
        linearlayoutmanager.getOrientation());
dividerItemDecoration.setDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.customdrawableshape));
recyclerview.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
```

Comment: Is that extra dot `.` after recyclerview a typo?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - How to add a dashed/dotted separator line for RecyclerView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39667195/android-how-to-add-a-dashed-dotted-separator-line-for-recyclerview)

Comment: @BlackHatSamurai oh yeah thats a typing mistake here

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40217754/4407266

Comment: Did you try it with a size? see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5501449/1837367

Answer (score 15):

you can use `DividerItemDecoration` class for adding lines.

here is example code

```
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(context, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
```

Comment: but i want the lines to be doted, thats why i am usting custom shape

Comment: ok then you need to create Custom Divider by extending RecyclerView.ItemDecoration class

Comment: One of the best solution I ever saw on DividerDecoration

Answer (score 0):

**Kotlin Version:**

```
recyclerview.addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL))
```